# Jquery DataTables: one column across the page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can't find a google search that gets me what I'm looking for.

I have a DataTable with one column, "phonenumber". There are 19,000+ rows in it. Seems a waste of space to have that one column taking up 300px of width and the rest of the page blank, and it would be convenient to have that column "wrap": to continue as another column or DataTable twice more across the page, i.e.

```
123456780
123456781
123456782
123456783
123456784
123456785
123456786
123456787
123456788
123456789
    next page >
```

becomes

```
123456780   123456790   123456101
123456781   123456791   123456112
123456782   123456792   123456123
123456783   123456793   123456134
123456784   123456794   123456145
123456785   123456795   123456156
123456786   123456796   123456167
123456787   123456797   123456178
123456788   123456798   123456189
123456789   123456799   123456190
                        next page >
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds like table is wrong tool for the job. What is your use case?

Comment: I'd agree with charlietfl, it doesn't sound like a table is what you want. One thing you could try is this here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37132 , it's a card view of a DataTable (example in that post is here: http://ghsfha.org/datatables_cards_labels.html ). Another option, if you really want a table, would be to preparse the data and put the values into multiple columns.

Comment: It's a way of accessing the list without going into the base tables in the database, so they can be deleted/updated so the non-tech person in the office can assist in the maintenance of the list.